# binary to string, better than a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, binary

Objective: Convert binary to string

Example: 0111010001100101011100110111010001100011011011110110010001100101 -> testCode (without space)

I use a dictionary and my function, i search a better way and more efficient

```
from textwrap import wrap

DICO = {'\x00': '00', '\x04': '0100', '\x08': '01000', '\x0c': '01100', 
'\x10': '010000', '\x14': '010100', '\x18': '011000', '\x1c': '011100',
' ': '0100000', '$': '0100100', '(': '0101000', ',': '0101100', '0': '0110000',
'4': '0110100', '8': '0111000', '<': '0111100', '@': '01000000',
'D': '01000100', 'H': '01001000', 'L': '01001100', 'P': '01010000',
'T': '01010100', 'X': '01011000', '\\': '01011100', '`': '01100000',
'd': '01100100', 'h': '01101000', 'l': '01101100', 'p': '01110000',
't': '01110100', 'x': '01111000', '|': '01111100', '\x03': '011',
'\x07': '0111', '\x0b': '01011', '\x0f': '01111', '\x13': '010011',
'\x17': '010111', '\x1b': '011011', '\x1f': '011111', '#': '0100011',
"'": '0100111', '+': '0101011', '/': '0101111', '3': '0110011', '7': '0110111',
';': '0111011', '?': '0111111', 'C': '01000011', 'G': '01000111',
'K': '01001011', 'O': '01001111', 'S': '01010011', 'W': '01010111',
'[': '01011011', '_': '01011111', 'c': '01100011', 'g': '01100111',
'k': '01101011', 'o': '01101111', 's': '01110011', 'w': '01110111',
'{': '01111011', '\x7f': '01111111', '\x02': '010', '\x06': '0110',
'\n': '01010', '\x0e': '01110', '\x12': '010010', '\x16': '010110',
'\x1a': '011010', '\x1e': '011110', '"': '0100010', '&': '0100110',
'*': '0101010', '.': '0101110', '2': '0110010', '6': '0110110', ':': '0111010',
'>': '0111110', 'B': '01000010', 'F': '01000110', 'J': '01001010',
'N': '01001110', 'R': '01010010', 'V': '01010110', 'Z': '01011010',
'^': '01011110', 'b': '01100010', 'f': '01100110', 'j': '01101010',
'n': '01101110', 'r': '01110010', 'v': '01110110', 'z': '01111010',
'~': '01111110', '\x01': '01', '\x05': '0101', '\t': '01001', '\r': '01101',
'\x11': '010001', '\x15': '010101', '\x19': '011001', '\x1d': '011101',
'!': '0100001', '%': '0100101', ')': '0101001', '-': '0101101',
'1': '0110001', '5': '0110101', '9': '0111001', '=': '0111101',
'A': '01000001', 'E': '01000101', 'I': '01001001', 'M': '01001101',
'Q': '01010001', 'U': '01010101', 'Y': '01011001', ']': '01011101',
'a': '01100001', 'e': '01100101', 'i': '01101001', 'm': '01101101',
'q': '01110001', 'u': '01110101', 'y': '01111001', '}': '01111101'}

def decrypt(binary):
    """Function to convert binary into string"""
    binary = wrap(binary, 8)
    ch = ''
    for b in binary:
        for i, j in DICO.items():
            if j == b:
                ch += i
    return ch
```

thank by advance,

Comment: What exactly do you want to improve on? Space or time complexity? What algorithm do you use currently, do you just split the string?

Comment: How do you decide if the sequence `010001` is `0100` (= `\x04`) followed by the start of a `01` sequence, or is the start of a hash mark character, `0100011`? If all characters have the same number of bits (presumable 7 or 8 bits), why isn't the code for `\x00` written as `00000000` in your example, but `00`? The example data leaves a lot of room for interpretation ...

Comment: @Redx, thank for your response, i search a better time of execution, else i keep my code

Comment: a strange thing about this code is that it will never match the short items such as '\x00': '00'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try

```
def decrypt(binary):
    """Function to convert binary into string"""
    return ''.join(( chr(int(p, 2)) for p in grouper(8,binary,'') ))
```

where grouper is taken from here http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes

or

```
def decrypt2(binary):
    """Function to convert binary into string"""
    return ''.join(( DICO_INVERTED[p] for p in grouper(8,binary,'') ))
```

that avoids to create temporary list

**EDIT**
as I was choisen to be the "right" answer I have to confess that I used the other answers. The point is here not to use generator list but generator expression and iterators

Comment: which one did you test the one with dictionary or the other one?

Comment: an average of 14 seconds, your proposal gives 0,006 seconds, super score, thanks a lot

Answer (score 14):

```
''.join([ chr(int(p, 2)) for p in wrap(binstr, 8) ])
```

What this does: `wrap` first splits your string up into chunks of 8. Then, I iterate through each one, and convert it to an integer (base 2). Each of those converted integer now get covered to a character with `chr`. Finally I wrap it all up with a `''.join` to smash it all together.

A bit more of a breakdown of each step of the `chr(int(p, 2))`:

```
>>> int('01101010', 2)
106
>>> chr(106)
'j'
```

To make it fit into your pattern above:

```
def decrypt(binary):
    """Function to convert binary into string"""
    binary = wrap(binary, 8)
    ch = ''
    for b in binary:
        ch += chr(int(b, 2))
    return ch
```

or

```
def decrypt(binary):
    """Function to convert binary into string"""
    return ''.join([ chr(int(p, 2)) for p in wrap(binary, 8) ])
```

This is definitely faster since it is just doing the math in place, not iterating through the dictionary over and over. Plus, it is more readable.

Comment: for the time, it's equivalent!

Comment: How big is your string? It could be that the `wrap` is taking the majority of the time and there is nothing much you can do about that. Either way, this is still way more readable than that monstrosity of a dictionary.

Comment: I dont' know for wrap but dictionary for length of 5000 --> 1.94 second and your code --> 3.45 seconds

Comment: @orangeoctopus Maybe it's worthwhile to replace `wrap(binary, 8)` with an iterable equivalent `(''.join(i) for i in grouper(8,binary,''))` using `grouper` from [here](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)? Or even the whole string with `''.join([ chr(int(''.join(p), 2)) for p in grouper(8,s)])`.

Comment: I was thinking that as well. Maybe the OP wants to try it.

Answer (score 3):

If execution speed it the most important for you, why not invert the roles of keys and values in your dict?! (If you also need the current dict, you could created an inverted version like this `{v:k for k, v in DICO.items()}`)

Now, you find directly the searched translation by key instead of looping through the whole dict.

Your new function would look like this:

```
def decrypt2(binary):
    """Function to convert binary into string"""
    binary = wrap(binary, 8)
    ch = ''
    for b in binary:
        if b in DICO_INVERTED:
            ch += DICO_INVERTED[b]
    return ch
```

Depending on the size of your binary string, you could gain some time by changing the way you construct your output-string (see [Efficient String Concatenation in Python](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) or [performance tips - string concatenation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation)). Using `join` seems promising. I would give it a try: `''.join(DICO_INVERTED.get(b, '') for b in binary)`

Comment: I also suggest creating the dict with code rather than typing it out.

Comment: @orangeoctopus, i don't typing the dict ;)

Comment: @user1125315 Did you try `join`? I'm interested in the performance gain you get (or not get)...